# An image is included in the animation but shouldn't

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I made this little animation and it works great. But, for some reason, the "image" from the `ChildView` is included into it whereas it was clearly not my intention.

The animation should only change the "size" of the "add" icon in the `toolbar` and nothing else. But the opacity of the "image" is also changed quite a bit.

I discovered two ways to fix the problem:

- Replacing the image from Core Data by a sample image like `Image("blabla")`,
- Removing the `@AppStorage` variable.

But, of course, I can't do that to my code.

Do you have an idea about what's going on?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ParentView: View {
    var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State private var isTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Tap me")
                    .onTapGesture { animateButton() }
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    ChildView(item: item)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Image("add")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                        .scaleEffect(!isTapped ? 1 : 1.20)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func animateButton() {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
            isTapped = true
        }
        withAnimation(.easeInOut.delay(0.20)) {
            isTapped = false
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    var item: FetchedResults<Item>.Element
    @AppStorage("something") private var something = false

    var body: some View {
        if let imageData = item.images.first?.imageData, let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove both `withAnimation` blocks and instead add `.animation(.easeInOut, value: isTapped)` after `scaleEffect`?

Comment: But how `isTapped` can get back to `false`, with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`?

Comment: @jnpdx can you post your solution as an answer so the OP can accept it? That way others can tell that a solution has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `withAnimation`, you always run the risk that some other action happening during the same cycle as the actual content inside your `withAnimation` closure will end up getting animated as well. Apparently, that's what's happening here.

The easiest way around that is to use an explicit `.animation` modifier on your `View` instead. So, in this case:

```
Image("add")
  .resizable()
  .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
  .scaleEffect(!isTapped ? 1 : 1.20)
  .animation(.easeInOut, value: isTapped)
```

Note that you can use an expression (like a ternary) to dynamically return a different type of animation instead of a static `.easeInOut`. So:

```
.animation(isTapped ? .easeInOut.delay(0.20) : .easeInOut, value: isTapped)
```